# Rails creating a new session every page view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session

I'm following the Agile RoR book somewhat to apply it to a project for school. It's going good until I get to sessions. I continually get Authenticity Invalid Tokens and when I look at my sessions table in the database, there's a new session being created every time I refresh the page. Is that right or is something messed up?

Thanks.

edit - I cleared my cookies (one from this app and another) and everything seems to be working okay now.

Comment: show your code where you are initializing your session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you blocking cookies to localhost?

Comment: I had two cookies for localhost. One from a previous app and an old version of this one. I wonder if that did it?